# EntityFramework find offending relation causing an "UpdateException"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We are using Entity Framework 6.1. with CodeFirst.

SaveChanges exits with the following exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:  "An error
>   occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details"

The InnerException is the following:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException:"Unable to determine a valid
>   ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to
>   foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated
>   values."

Very informative, however before I can fix it I need to know which relation(s) are causing this problem. Is this information somewhere hidden in these exceptions?

Comment: You need to provide more information such as the code block that the exception is encompassing. If we can see the entity class and your method of mapping the entity in question.  The stacktrace might also be helpful in narrowing it down.

Comment: @JamesShaw Thanks for taking the time James. The question is not: what is wrong with my model. The questions is: does the exception contain any information about the offending relations. (it is not in the stacktrace that reports that SaveChanges trew.)

Comment: I see the predicament.  Perhaps the following might lead you to your answer?  http://codemeek.blogspot.ca/2013/11/resolve-entity-framework-error-occurred.html